# Github_server settings and implementation in jenkins job

Tags: git, jenkins, github

sorry in advance if it's going to be long - I'm new to Jenkins.

I would like to change the way we approach git in our Jenkins (version 2.89.4).
We mainly use multibranch pipeline projects.
I've defined a github_server under "configure system" using a personal token I've generated on github side, and created with this token a webhook to our Jenkins on github side as well (webhook status OK).
When I try to change a current multibranch pipeline project to work with the github_server (using github_source), the build finishes but the folder is empty. Re-editing the configuration is not possible since it gets stuck on loading because of the SCM part. If I choose no scm, still - folder empty.

Please explain how github_server can be used in multibranch pipeline projects.

---

the job/project configuration:
branch sources: github source (type).
github project url: https://github.com/orgname/reponame.git.
repo provider: github plugin from global settings
manage hooks is checked
repository requested permission: pull
scm factory: no scm
handlers: branch handlers- added all except branch restrictions
property strategy: all branches get the same properties

build configuration:
mode: by Jenkinsfile
script path - Jenkinsfile (exists in the repo)

scan multibranch pipeline triggers- periodically if not otherwise run , interval 5 min

orphaned item strategy- discard all items

---

That's it. really hope you can assist :) If there's any detail I haven't mentioned, let me know.

Thanks,
Hila

Comment: Did you upgrade your git client version?

Comment: where? on my machine? how is it related to Jenkins not being able to get to fetch the repo intermittently ?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/https-cloning-errors/ and https://github.com/blog/809-git-dumb-http-transport-to-be-turned-off-in-90-days

Comment: solved the github error. issue with one of the slaves.. I edited my question because I still want to implement the github_server configuration in our projects. Please take a look.